# Simples login Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Eu já tenho um login principal com o Firebase auth. Mas eu preciso implementar um outro login dentro desse sistema, pois o cliente pode adicionar outros administradores. O login será simples mesmo, só verificar se a senha e e-mail conferem.

tenho esse método que faz o login:

```
public void retrive(String uid, String senha) {
    raiz
            .child(CHILD) // ex: adms
            .child(uid) // ex: rafael@email
            .equalTo(senha,"senha")
            .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.getValue() != null) {
                        // ok
                    }else {
                        // false
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    //false
                }
            });
}
```

Meu Firebase Json esta assim: pai adm e filhos:

```
{
    "rafael@gmailcom": {
        "ativo": true,
        "codigo": "rafael@gmailcom",
        "dataNascimento": 944515274,
        "email": "rafael@gmail.com",
        "nome": "Rafael Aparecido da silva",
        "privilegios": {
            "ACESSO_FINANCEIRO": true,
            "AGENDAR_CONSULTA": false,
            "CADASTRO_PACIENTE ": false,
            "CADASTRO_PACIENTE_": false,
            "MANTER_ADM": false,
            "RECEBER_PAGAMENTO": true
        },
        "senha": "teste"
    }
}
```

Não consigo fazer que ele traga o usuário desejado.

Answer (score 1):

O Firebase não permite fazer uma Query baseada em 2 condições. O que significa que você terá de fazer o login em 2 etapas:

1.Procurar o user com esse ID

2.Verificar se a senha está correcta:

```
public void retrive(String uid, String senha) {
    raiz.child(CHILD) // ex: adms
        .child(uid) // ex: rafael@email
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.child("senha").getValue() == Senha) {
                        // ok
                    }else {
                        // false
                    }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //false
            }
        });
}
```